# 3 tier arch. in diff projects

Tags: c#

This is the solution as far as it goes.

[image]

BOL. Business Object Layer.
BL. Business Layer.
DAL. Data Layer.
(No web page in the solution since it will be a php one developed in a later process)

**BOL** references **BL**- then **BL** references **DAL**.

I pretty much guess you know what's inside of each .cs file. So I really like this 3 tier architecture and keeping things separated (first time working this way).
Now, when it comes to send and get data through the layers I ran across a few issues.

For instance: BL (methods.cs)

```
  public class Methods
    {
        LineaDAL obj = new LineaDAL();
        public DataSet GetLinea()
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds = obj.GetLineaDAL();
            return ds;
        }
     ////more code
     }
```

This works great, create an object from DAL (which is referenced) and then call DAL and retrieve data over a `DataSet`.
That's cool, and it works great for getting something out of the DAL/SQL.

But now I'm working on an update, and I'd like BL to call a DAL function sending to it a parameter. First thing I've tried that parameter to be was of course an object from BOL. Wasn't possible for obvious reasons, BL doesn't know about BOL.

When this happened I started reading and found some good approachs. One of them, is to create a DTO... I don't like this one very much since I really like the top-down separated-enviroment in the tiers and layers. So I kept looking and found something related to `EventArgs` and some `Interfaces` as well, but I'm still scratching my head to see if I'm in the right path.

I'm cool working BL through DAL, DataSets and stuff.
But is there a way to work with **BOL** Objects in the top layer? If this is not possible in order to save the top-down references, should I use `DataSets` for BOL <-> BL aswell? Is `EventArgs` the way to go?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not a tiered architecture - it is a layered one. Tiers normally mean that the different layers run on _different machines_.

Comment: they will in the future once the system is running, hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you need a bunch of entities that can be referenced and shared between the layers, then these should live in a standalone project, that all other projects can reference.

The if your different application layers are distributed amongst different machines, the entities library can just be distributed with each layer.  EventArgs is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: wouldn't that destroy the rule "top knows about bottom, but bottom doesn't know about top? Im trying to save future time when it's time for changes.

Comment: Not really. Entities are visible everywhere. They don't fit in a specific layer, but all layers. After all, in the case of web services the client and the server layers need to know about same entities, whether they are auto generated proxies or shared libraries.  And the DAL needs to know about them too.

Answer (score 1):

If you split across machines, then you will have some sort of data contract to send across the wire. So, you will most-likely need to introduce DTOs at that point.

What is the DL layer going to return when you come to do a select (read)?  For the reasons you state, you cannot return a BOL object for the select (BL has no reference to BOL).

It seems a bit messy to me to return a DataSet (which is sort of a data layer concept) up to the BL.  So, I would suggest creating a BL object (DTO) that you map to from the DataSet and then expose that object up to BOL.  This sorts out your references and aligns the responsibility of each layer more distinctly.

Comment: BL calls select method from DAL, DAL method returns a DataSet. So what you basically say is to use a DTO in order to "transform" the DataSet so I can then present it to BOL. Am I getting you right? If so, DTO should be in a separated project? because you said "BL Object" but if I create a new object in Methods.cs (BL layer) or another layer inside that project that one will be still with no-communication to its top layer (BOL). Sorry for the mess and thanks for the help.

Comment: @DanielSh. Typically, you would create another shared dll between BL and BOL. You could name this project "contracts" or something similar. This dll is logically owned by BL, because it is exposing BL data, but can be referenced on both sides. If you then move to a split over machines, there are ways to generate the client contract on the BOL side (wsdl etc).